# how to format a complex linq expression?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I've got kind of a monster `linq` expression:

```
public static class HeaderOperators
{
    public static IDictionary<string, string> GetValues(IReadOnlyList<string> keys, IHeaderDictionary headers, string defaultValue)
    {
        return keys.Select(x => x.ToLower()).Intersect(headers.Keys.Select(x => x.ToLower()))
            .Select(k => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(k.ToLower(), headers[k.ToLower()]))
            .Union(keys.Select(x => x.ToLower()).Where(k => !headers.Keys.Select(x => x.ToLower()).Contains(k.ToLower())).Select(k => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(k.ToLower(), defaultValue)))
            .ToDictionary(p => p.Key.ToLower(), p => p.Value);
    }
}
```

**Are there any tools available to format this nicely so it's readable?**

Alternatively, perhaps there's a syntax that's more manageable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would split it to be more readable:

```
public static class HeaderOperators
{
    public static IDictionary<string, string> GetValues(IReadOnlyList<string> keys, IHeaderDictionary headers, string defaultValue)
    {
        var firstCollection = keys
            .Select(x => x.ToLower()).Intersect(headers.Keys.Select(x => x.ToLower()))
            .Select(k => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(k.ToLower(), headers[k.ToLower()]));

        var secondCollection = keys
            .Select(x => x.ToLower())
            .Where(k => !headers.Keys.Select(x => x.ToLower()).Contains(k.ToLower()))
            .Select(k => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(k.ToLower(), defaultValue));

        return
            firstCollection.Union(secondCollection).ToDictionary(p => p.Key.ToLower(), p => p.Value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As it is more chained than nested, I'd just format it something like this:

```
return keys.Select( x => x.ToLower() )
           .Intersect( headers.Keys.Select(x => x.ToLower()) )
           .Select( k => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(k.ToLower(), headers[k.ToLower()]) )
           .Union( keys.Select(x => x.ToLower() )
           .Where( k => !headers.Keys.Select(x => x.ToLower()).Contains(k.ToLower()) )
           .Select( k => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(k.ToLower(), defaultValue)) )
           .ToDictionary( p => p.Key.ToLower(), p => p.Value );
```

And... add comments at the end of each line.

Comment: very nice approach, however, would you perhaps lean towards the other answer as i did? why or why not?